# Accidentally baked flatbread with oxygen absorber -- is flatbread safe to eat?

Tags: flatbread

We just accidentally baked some trader joes flatbread and didn't notice the oxygen absorber went in the oven with it. If you're unfamiliar, this is the little packet that preserves the food with big words "DO NOT EAT" printed on the side. The packet didn't open, just stayed stuck to the bottom of the flatbread while it baked. However I'm wondering if anything poisonous might have out gassed and been absorbed into the pizza dough? Maybe I'm paranoid, but I don't feel quite safe eating it now.

Oxygen absorber only lists a brand name: AGELESS. From [this link](http://www.agelessoxygenabsorbers.com/AgelessFeatures.html) its the "ZPT" type. The first one listed on the page.

The flatbread (and the oxygen absorber) was cooked at 425 degrees Fahrenheit for about 10 minutes.

Comment: What type of oxygen absorber was it?  Does it say on the packet?  I have seen a variety of types, some are safe some are not.

Comment: @Orbling, see updated question

Comment: Which type does it look like from these [AGELESS absorbers](http://www.agelessoxygenabsorbers.com/AgelessFeatures.html).

Comment: @Orbling, its the ZPT type.

Comment: tip: let the neighbors try some, wait a day, and see how they fare =P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you have identified the oxygen scavenger as a [ZPT-type AGELESS device](http://www.mgc.co.jp/eng/products/abc/ageless/type.html), I believe the active ingredient is mainly iron oxide, rust, which isn't inherently harmful.  However I do not know what the packaging material is made from.

**AGELESS ZPT-type:**

[image: AGELESS ZPT-type]

I did find some data on the [Mitsuibishi website for AGELESS](http://www.mgc.co.jp/eng/products/abc/ageless/note.html), stating that some types are alright when microwaved, but there were no direct references to direct heating.

If it were me, I would remove the area around the patch and eat it, but I am not an expert and I would recommend that you contact them directly to be sure.

Tel: 212-687-9030 (US)
Email: AGELESS@mgc-a.com

Comment: It's possible that the package is made of Tyvek. Per [Tyvek's MSDS](http://msds.dupont.com/msds/pdfs/EN/PEN_09004a3580429c46.pdf), it doesn't look like it should have given off anything especially bad for you at that temperature. It only starts to burn and give off toxic gases at over 600 °F.  I'm not an expert, but it seems like this should be reasonably safe so long as you manage to avoid the package itself.

Comment: From my reading, I'd go ahead and try it as long as the packaging itself didn't get hot enough to char or melt. The active ingredient is iron, which scavanged the free oxygen by rusting. Neither can be modified by heating to only 450 degrees. The packaging is rated as food safe. So that only leaves the question of actual melt or burning. Of course, I am not a chemist or a lawyer, your mileage may vary, etc. But I would taste it and eat it myself.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say if it isn't much of a hassel, just dunk this portion and bake more bread.. It's better to be safe than sorry. And for the least you'll clear your mind of the possible side effects of the absorber and eat with ease, and enjoy the flatbread..